# On Proving The nth odd number is 2n − 1 Through Induction, And A Few Extensions

Tags: proof-verification, induction

What I've done so far is to prove it for the n+1th number:

$(2n-1)+2=2(n+1)-1$. Because any odd number +2 is equals to the next odd number. And in the proof, it is given that 2n-1 is an odd number.

$2n+1=2n+2-1$

$2n+1=2n+1$

What I'm worried though, is if by assuming "since any odd number +2 is equals to the next odd number", am I being circular? Am I using circular reasoning?

And also, thinking about this, how would one prove that for any odd number n, the next odd number is n+2? How would they do that without being circular?

Please give the answer very simple, at the level of a pre-calculus student. I am just starting proofs for fun, and am still at a very basic level. I haven't even touched on sigma notation yet.

Comment: When you're wary about circular arguments, it's best to strip everything away and start from scratch. In particular: *What is your definition of an odd number?* (Also, since you're going to discuss the "$n$-th" odd number, just to be clear: *Which odd number do you associate with $n=1$?*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2n – 1 = 2n -2 + 1 = 2(n – 1) + 1 = 2k + 1$ where $k = n-1$ is an integer and
$ 2n -1$ is odd by definition

Answer (score 0):

$2n\ -\ 1$ is clearly odd because $(2n\ -\ 1)\ \text{mod}\ 2\ =\ 1$.  So $2n\ -\ 1$ is an arbitrary odd number by definition.  But adding 2 results in $2n\ +\ 1$ which is odd for the same reason.  Hence, adding 2 to an arbitrary odd number results in another odd number, specifically the next consecutive odd number.